# Global Bash Completion Scripts

Tags: linux, debian, bash, bashrc, debian-buster

I have a [Bash completion script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/v2.4.0/utils/wp-completion.bash). Is there a place I can put it on my system, so that it will be automatically `source`-ed for any user that uses a Bash shell?

I would prefer a solution that does not require me to edit a configuration file in each user's `$HOME` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Put it into `/etc/bash_completion.d`

Comment: Thanks. That directory does not exist on my system. If I create it, will those scripts be loaded automatically or is there some more configuration required?

Comment: Yes, but only if those users include a command like `. /etc/bash_completion` in their bashrc files or in `/etc/bash_profile` (`/etc/bash.bashrc` on Debian/Ubuntu, where this code exists but is commented). This actually requires the `bash-completion` package to be installed on your system (which I highly recommend).